# Where are references and pointers enforced?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

From what I understand, pointers hold the addresses of a value, and references can be thought as `const` pointers.

From this sample code:

```
int main() {
    int i = 1;
    int &ri = i;
    int *pi = &i;
    return 0;
}
```

The disassembly, both pointer and reference look exactly the same:

```
main:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 16
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12], 1
    lea eax, [ebp-12]
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], eax
    lea eax, [ebp-12]
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], eax
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

Are pointers and references only enforced by the compiler?

Comment: struggling to understand what you mean by "enforced"  . They are language features and they are working as intended

Comment: BTW inspecting unoptimized assembly is a poor way to learn , as you only really learn about one particular implementation's implementation details.  You might overlook the fact that `int ri = 1; int &i = ri;` would have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I understand, pointers hold the addresses of a value, and references can be thought as const pointers.

That's a simplistic view. The standard defines their behavior. It's up to an implementation to figure out how to support that behavior.

Given

```
int i = 0;
int& ref = i;
int* ptr = &i;
```

the standard mandates that

```
&ref == &i
```

and

```
&ptr != &i;
```

Hence, it may make sense to think of references as const pointers for some aspects of its behavior but it definitely does not make sense for all aspects of its behavior.